# Access violation writing data to a doubly linked list

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, doubly-linked-list

I got the following error:
 `0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000040.`Which I assume means that the new contact is empty,when adding a new information to a doubly linked list using pointers.Ths is where I finish the function:

```
curr->next = newContact;
newContact->prev = curr;
newContact->next = NULL;
```

So I added the following if..else loop to check if curr is equal to the newContact and add it to the list.But that didn't work either..

```
if(curr-> newContact)
{
    curr->next = newContact;
    newContact->prev = NULL;
}
else
{
curr->next = newContact;
newContact->prev = curr;
newContact->next = NULL;
}
```

This is the complete function for reference:

```
 int addContact(struct contact *theList)
    {
        struct contact *newContact, *curr;

        // create the new structure
        newContact = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
        if( newContact == NULL )
        {   // if true, then no memory left - oops
            return(0);
        }
        // find the end of the list
        curr = theList;
        // scroll through the list 
        if(curr != NULL)
        {

            while( curr->next != NULL)
            {
                curr = curr->next;
            }

        }
        // now have the last contact
        // add the new one here.
        printf("\nEnter a surname: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(newContact->sname);
        printf("\nEnter a first name: ");
        gets(newContact->fname);
        printf("\nEnter a phone: ");
        gets(newContact->phone);
        printf("\nEnter a company: ");
        gets(newContact->company);

        // need to hook the new contact to
        // end of list

        if(curr-> newContact)
        {
            curr->next = newContact;
            newContact->prev = NULL;


        }
        else
        {
        curr->next = newContact;
        newContact->prev = curr;
        newContact->next = NULL;
        }
        return(1);
    }//add
```

I cant see where I'm gone wrong in the check.Any ideas?Thanks

Comment: Chances are either cur or newContact are NULL

Comment: `curr-> newContact` is funny

Comment: looking at the complete function can you see why that is?

Answer (score 1):

The access violation, and the address `0x00000040` in the error message, are telling you that you have not properly initialized `curr` which is a pointer to a structure of some sort. Odds are you declared it but never allocated memory for it or set it to point to a valid storage space.

I would bet money that `curr` is `NULL` and `next` is 0x40 bytes into the structure.

Expanding on your edited question... look at this block of code... what happens if `curr` **is** `NULL` ?? You're testing for the possibility, but then if it is `NULL` you don't do anything about it.

```
   // find the end of the list
    curr = theList;
    // scroll through the list 
    if(curr != NULL)
    {

        while( curr->next != NULL)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why it is null?

Comment: Yes,If it's NULL then I haven't added any condition.Im guessing if it is `NULL` I should set the `theList` to `curr` but I have already done this.Dont understand why list isn't being assinged to variable `curr`..

Comment: You are setting `curr = theList;` so `curr` points to whatever `theList` points to which is, most likely, `NULL` -- how and where is `theList` initialized and to what?